# gitolite/git: how can I bypass a pre-receive hook on demand?

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I wrote a pre-receive hook that secure static analyze the submitted code and prevent the push whenever some code contains some bugs/weakness/vulnerabilities.

Unlikely in some cases cppcheck reports some false positive and I would like to give to sw engineers the possibility to quickly bypass the hooks.

How can I achieve that on gitolite/git ?

I'm aware of the comments that can instruct cppcheck to report some findings but I can't use it.